# Ignore extra fields found during transformation by "aliasToBean" transformer

Tags: java, hibernate, resultset

I am aware of the usage of aliasToBean transformer : It calls setters for various fields found in a query's result set on a POJO and constructs the POJO.

Now in a fairly complicated query, i am fetching a lot of extra fields other than the lots that are there in the POJO(why i am fetching extra fields is due to query structure) ; is there a way to tell this transformer to ignore the fields for which it does not find setters?

Answer (score 0):

In yourPOJO.hbm.xml, enable direct field access for your properties whose setters should be ignored through the access="field" mapping attribute:

```
<property name="name" access="field">
    <column name="NAME" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

Comment: I want to ignore some additional fields which i have fetched in the query which are not a part of the POJO...a different use-case